# Using parallel to grep patterns from a hugefile and print each pattern to a new file

Tags: parallel-processing, grep

I am trying to print the patterns searched using grep from a file into a new files having a pattern each, but since the original file is huge it takes a lot of time. I am aiming for something on these lines:

```
cat All_microbes_nonewline.fna | parallel --pipe --block 2000M -j5 fgrep -A1 -f {} < kunju.txt > {}.fna
```

Could you please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are looking for:

parallel --pipe --block 2000M grep pattern < All_microbes_nonewline.fna

Comment: Hi Bob. I would like to use fgrep -A1 -f for the patterns file as the file looks as: pattern1 line2 pattern2 line4 pattern3 line6 pattern4 line8 .... And I want to print pattern1 line2 as file pattern1.fna, pattern2 line4 as file pattern2.fna and so on.. All lines are single continuous lines